# Immersion is a diffeomorphism.

Tags: differential-topology, solution-verification

Clearly I suppose to put the condition $n > 1$ in use. So my proof must went wrong.. Could someone help me take a look at it? Thanks!

> Suppose $X$ is a smooth, compact, connected $n$-manifold without boundary which admits an immersion to $S^n$. Show that if $n > 1$, then this immersion is a diffeomorphism.

By local immersion theorem,

> **Local Immersion Theorem**
>   Suppose that $f: X \to Y$ is an immersion at $x$, and $y = f(x)$. Then there exist local coordinates around $x$ and $y$ such that
>   $$f(x_1, \dots, x_k) = (x_1, \dots, x_k, 0, \dots, 0).$$
>   In other words,$x$ is locally equivalent to the canonical immersion near $x$.

Therefore, the image of $f$ is open, since $(x_1, \dots, x_k)$ is open in $X$ so $(x_1, \dots, x_k, 0, \dots, 0)$ is open in $Y$. Also, because $X$ is compact, $f$ is proper. Therefore, $f$ is an embedding. According to the theorem, $f$ is an embedding.

> **Theorem** An embedding $f: X \to Y$ maps $X$ diffeomorphically onto a submanifold of $Y$.

However, continuous functions preserves compactness, hence the image of $f$ is closed. The only closed and open subset of $Y$ is $Y$ itself. Hence $f$ is surjective. Therefore, since $f$ maps $X$ diffeomorphically onto a submanifold of $Y$, the submanifold is $Y$. And consequently, $f$ is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: An embedding is also injective. $z \mapsto z^2$ is an immersion $S^1 \to S^1$ that is not injective.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry! I accidentally hit enter before finishing my response.

Comment: Hi @DanielFischer, thanks - I'm sorry I missed the last paragraph. I just added.

Comment: @AviSteiner, I see what you meant, I'm sorry. Not sure how come I left the last paragraph.. Just added. Thanks!!

Comment: "Therefore, since $f$ maps $X$ diffeomorphically onto a submanifold of $Y$", you have not shown that, and - see above - you can't deduce that for dimension $1$. Question: do you know what a covering is?

Comment: You're solution is forgetting a couple of things: First, you need to show, as @DanielFischer pointed out, that $f$ is one-to-one. Second, saying that $(x_1,\ldots,x_k)$ is open in $X$ doesn't make sense. I think what you mean is that $f$ takes an open neighborhood of $x$ to an open neighborhood of $y$.

Comment: @DanielFischer True, but it'd have been unhelpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you have is in fact a "local embedding" instead of a global embedding. You need to be slightly careful since different books may use different definition of "embedding" and "immersion". But anyway, now you have an immersion $f$ which is *locally* a diffeomorphism

$$M\overset{f}{\to} S^n$$

For a *local* embedding to fail to be a global one, you must have overlapped image, or equivalently have $f$ failing to be injective. This amounts to saying that $f$ must be a covering map of $S^n$, or equivalently $M$ is a covering space of $S^n$. This rules out the possibility of $S^1$ since its fundamental group is not trivial. Now for $n>1$, since it is well known that they have trivial fundamental group, therefore $f$ must be a 1-folded covering map, or equivalently a *global* embedding.

Comment: Aha, got it! Thank you so much shallpion!

Comment: So the theorem says, given a local embedding, I have a local diffeomorphism; given a glocal embedding, I have a glocal diffeomorphism?

Comment: I think you are right.

Comment: +1 from me but I just wanted to add that the fact that $f$ is a covering map depends on the fact that $M$ is a compact, boundaryless manifold.  There are plenty of non-compact or compact-with-boundary manifolds $M$ which admit immersions into $S^n$ but fail to be diffeomorphisms.  For example, if $M$ is the open or closed northern hemisphere and $f$ is the inclusion map.

Answer (score 1):

Acturally, it should also be noted that the dimension of $M$ plays a critical rule, since the claim $f$ is open is a consequence of the invariance of domain. The problem can be split into a few well-known results:

(1) Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, if $f:U\to f(U)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a diffeomorphism, then $f(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

(2) If $f:M\to N$ is a local diffeomorphism between two compact connected manifolds, then $f$ is a smooth covering map.

(3) Let $f:M\to N$ is a covering map between two manifolds. Further suppose that $N$ is simply connected, then $f$ is a diffeomorphism.

So for the problem given above, the dimension assumption guarantees that $f$ is indeed a local diffeomorphism not just a local embedding. The assumption that $n>1$ guarantees that $S^n$ is simply connected.